# Jquery Animated File Tree - How to transition each li height to auto

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I currently have my basic code for a animated tree structure using css and jquery but with my limited knowledge of jquery I am having trouble with my argument, see below. On line 3 I am saying if the li has the class expanded then add a transition which will open and close the li. If you try my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/E9vcz/) you will see that it works for the top level li but not for each individual li within the tree. Is there a way that I can get jQuery to work out whether an li within the structure is expanded or not instead of treating every li the same? Thank you

```
$(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var expanded = $(this).is(".expanded");
        if (expanded) 
        {
            $(this).transition({ 'max-height': '20px', overflow: 'hidden' }, 500, 'in', function () {$(this).removeClass("expanded"); });
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).transition({ 'max-height': $(this).get(0).scrollHeight, overflow: ''}, 500, 'out', function () { $(this).addClass("expanded"); });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the event reaches the parent, and the elements collapse.

You need to use [`.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent that.

That will tell the event to only execute in the lowest level it matches, so the event will not bubble upwards to the parent LI which are expanded.

```
$(function () {
    $("li").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        var expanded = $(this).is(".expanded");
        if (expanded) 
        {
            $(this).transition({ 'max-height': '20px', overflow: 'hidden' }, 500, 'in', function () {$(this).removeClass("expanded"); });
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).transition({ 'max-height': $(this).get(0).scrollHeight, overflow: ''}, 500, 'out', function () { $(this).addClass("expanded"); });
        }
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLbQd/)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense but in your example when i open a 2nd tier LI then the LI after it in the list disappears. Test case  - click plants then flowers and the trees li dissapears which is adjacent to flowers

Comment: @Parallel2ne here is an alternative approach (attaching the event to just the title) http://jsfiddle.net/mDDRx/ . The fact the li after in the list disappears is because you manually set the max height to the scrollHeight.

Comment: I worked of a tutorial to minize and mazimise a paragraph so maybe it is not suitable for this hierachy. Could you suggest an alternative solution to my scrollHeight method as that would answer my question fully and help me out so much. Thanks again for your time

Comment: That works very well. Thank you for your help. I will try and make a css3 version too